# How would I pretty print a python docstring?

Tags: python, docstring

I have a python file that has raw strings as the docstrings.

```
def a():
    '\n\tthis\n\tis\n\tthe docstring.\n\t'
    print 'hello world'
```

how would I rewrite the docstring to look like

```
def a():
    """
    this
    is
    the docstring.
    """
    print 'hello world'
```

Comment: This makes me wonder how the docstring got written like that in the first place.  It seems that it would be better to fix this at the source (as I don't know any humans who write docstrings that way ;-)

Comment: after an `ast.NodeTransform` and I can't get the code generator to write it in the pretty format without rewriting all strings.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by pretty print? Obviously interpret escape sequences, but also indentation, word wrapping, conformance to [PEP 257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), ...? If so, please *list* your requirements for that transformation explicitely.

Comment: @baallezx if you have code, provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the output

Comment: Which python version are you using? My *guess* is that in python2 you probably want `the_docstring.decode('string-escape')` and you want `the_docstring.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')` in python3.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - do you mean a minimal example of the the codegenerator or the ast.NodeTransformer? Because if you mean a minimal example of what my code looks like after the transform and code generation the first example above is a good example for the output file I am getting. Plus the code generator I am using is from the `astor` library with the codegen.to_source(curr_ast) call.

Comment: Is there nothing available to the NodeTransformer that gives you the original string style?

Comment: @user2357112 the `ast` has Str nodes that contain the string for the node. But it does not have an option for an original string style. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Does [`ast.get_docstring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.get_docstring) help?

Comment: @user2357112 - it really doesn't specifically help this is more of a code generator issue. But at least I can use that function to differentiate the strings from the docstrings.

Comment: Looks like you've already submitted an issue on Github. I hope it gets addressed. If you end up writing something to do it, you might want to submit a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using the [`inspect.getsoucelines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) and some regex:

```
import inspect
import re

def update_doc(func, indent='    '):
    sourcelines = inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0]
    doc = func.__doc__
    if doc is not None:
        ind = [line.decode('string_escape').strip()[1:-1] 
                                                 for line in sourcelines].index(doc)
        sourcelines[ind] = '{}"""{}"""\n'.format(indent, 
                                           re.sub(r'\n([ \t]+)', r'\n'+indent, doc))
    return ''.join(sourcelines)
```

**Demo:**

```
def a():
    '\n\tthis\n\tis\n\tthe docstring.\n\t'
    print 'hello world'
print update_doc(a)

def b():
    '\n    This is\n    not so lengthy\n    docstring\n    '
    print 'hmm...'
print update_doc(b)
```

**Output:**

```
def a():
    """
    this
    is
    the docstring.
    """
    print 'hello world'

def b():
    """
    This is
    not so lengthy
    docstring
    """
    print 'hmm...'
```

P.S: I have not tested it thoroughly yet, but this should get you started.

Comment: But how could I use this to actually rewrite a file? Add this function to every file and call this method after each function, then use something like sed to capture the output and save it to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

[Pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) allows to create, harmonize and convert docstrings.

It can't currently propose to expand raw description as `\n`, but it could be easy to add this functionality. You can open an issue to request it.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching google but it turns out you can just call the vanilla `print` function to print some docs like my sklearn support vector classifier, like this: [image: print doc pretty]